# Multiple Facebook Live reaction polls in 1 post

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase

Does anybody know how to add multiple polls in a Facebook live post, as shown in this example by Super Deluxe: https://www.facebook.com/superdeluxevideo/videos/416419238702632/.

My idea was to create a button to store the current reactions count as an object in a (Firebase) database and subtract that from the reactions count given from the API to start from 0 on every new round. The problem with this is that when people react on the first poll and give a different reaction on the next, it subtracts the first reaction and puts that reaction into the negative.

For example: If the user pressed WOW on the first poll, the count is WOW:1 LOVE:0. When the poll is reset, those umbers are subtracted from what is being taken from the Facebook Graph API. So, if on the next poll, this user presses LOVE, the count switches to WOW:-1 LOVE:1.

Here's a basic example of the code I have, using Firebase to store the reaction values.

```
// Firebase config
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
var dbCounter = database.ref('/counter');

var access_token = 'ACCESS_TOKEN', // PASTE HERE YOUR FACEBOOK ACCESS TOKEN
    pageID = 'PAGE_ID', //Paste your Facebook Page ID here
    postID = 'POST_ID', // PASTE HERE YOUR POST ID
    postID = pageID+'_'+postID,
    refreshTime = 5, // Refresh time in seconds
    counter = {
        love : 0,
        wow : 0
    },
    cachedCounter = counter;

var reactions = ['LOVE', 'WOW'].map(function (e) {
        var code = 'reactions_' + e.toLowerCase();
        return 'reactions.type(' + e + ').limit(0).summary(total_count).as(' + code + ')'
    }).join(',');

var refreshCounts = function() {
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/' + postID + '?fields=' + reactions + '&access_token=' + access_token;
    $.getJSON(url, function(res){
        counter.love = res.reactions_love.summary.total_count;
        counter.wow = res.reactions_wow.summary.total_count;
        $('.reaction.love .count').text(counter.love);
        $('.reaction.wow .count').text(counter.wow);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Update the value of cachedCounter every time the database is updated
    dbCounter.on('value', function(res){
        // res.val() starts with the same value as the default counter
        cachedCounter = res.val();
    });

    // Only runs once
    dbCounter.once('value').then(function(res){
        setInterval(refreshCounts, refreshTime * 1000);
        refreshCounts();
    });

    // Reset counters while keeping count of reactions for new poll
    $('button.reset-count').click( function() {
        // Save current counter in database
        dbCounter.set(counter);
        // Set counters to 0
        $('.reaction .count').text(0);
        return false;
    } );
});
```

Would anybody happen to know how Super Deluxe is resetting the reaction count values in their implementation?

Comment: Facebook does not want you to use reactions in such a way, see https://en.facebookbrand.com/assets/reactions: _“Don't use Reactions for polls in video where the whole stream consists of static or looping graphics or images.”_ (And because the “argument” of “but look at the example, they are doing it too!!!1” can be expected to be brought up now: Bank robbery is also not legal just because you see people doing it.)

Comment: @CBroe How do you know what material jtpatton is showing on Facebook Live? It says not to use Reactions in polls only where the stream has static or looping graphics. Both Super Deluxe (as linked) and quite possibly jtpatton's project use real, live content with polling built in, which is totally allowed in FB's ToS. Also just gonna say, connections between bank robbery and Facebook's API might be a little over the top?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. It essentially came down to this:

**If you run multiple polls in one video, you can't keep just on two reactions (e.g. Like/love) for the entire thing.**

Let's use this scenario:

> Poll 1 starts: 0 likes, 0 loves (nobody has voted yet)
>
> Poll 1 ends: 100 likes, 200 loves. Loves win 66% / 33%.

Then, a few minutes later, we run Poll #2. If we reset the default back down to zero, that means we set an offset of whatever likes and loves are on the video when the new poll starts. So, we remove those from the votes.

> Poll 2 starts: (from last vote) 100 likes, 200 loves. Offset set at -100, -200, so effectively 0 likes and 0 loves.

Now, when Poll 2 ends, that's when it gets difficult. Let's look at the scenario where we have a mix of people who have already voted and ones that are new.

> 5 people switch their vote from love to like.
>
> 5 people are new and decide to like it.
>
> Love gets no additional votes.
>
> Poll 2 ends: 10 likes (110 total likes - 100 offset from last vote), -5 loves (195 total loves - 200 offset from last vote).

We don't want that negative number.

**My solution was to:**

- Switch from like/love to another reaction set (like haha/wow) every other vote
- Reset the count (like the above offset) at the beginning of each voting period

This way, if people are voting, they're switching back and forth and effectively "resetting" the vote each time.